# On the sum of degrees of neighbors of a vertex

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple and undirected and $u\in V(G)$. I was wondering if someone could tell my why $$\sum_{v\in N(u)}d_v =d_u +2e(G[N(u)])+e(N(u),N_2 (u))?$$

Here, $N_2 (u)$ is the set of vertices at distance 2 from u in $G$ and $e(N(u),N_2 (u))$ is the number of edges between $N(u)$ and $N_2 (u)$.

Comment: You should define the terms. What is $N_2(u)$?

Comment: @coffeemath I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Probably a common notation I didn't know... One more thing... does $G[N(u)]$ refer to the part of the graph G which lies in the neighborhood of $u$? If so does it include vertex $u$ itself? Thanks.

Comment: @coffeemath Sure. In fact, $G[N(u)]$ is the subgraph of $G$ induced by $N(u)$. i.e. is the graph whose vertex set is $N(u)$  and whose edge set consists of all of the edges in $E(G)$ that have both endpoints in $N(u)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First term in the equation defines no of edges connecting the neighbors of vertex u (edges incident upon vertex u) also known as degree of vertex u.

Second term defines no of edges exists b/w the neighbors of vertex u. Since, it is a undirected graph, we have to multiply with 2 (repeated edges if we calculate for each vertex).

Third term defines no of edges b/w the neighbors of vertex u which are 1 distance away from u and 2nd neighbors of vertex u which are 2 distance away from u.

In a simple way, we can say this we are summing up the no of edges incident (degree of nodes) upon neighbors of a given vertex. i.e no of edges connecting given vertex from neighbors, no of edges exists among the neighbors and no of edges which are 1 distance away from neighbors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry, what do you mean by $b/w$?

Comment: b/w is a common abbreviation of "between".